# Wifi works only if I wait in login screen for networks to be available

Tags: wireless, 16.04, login, suspend

I've got cleanly installed Ubuntu 16.04 in Acer Aspire V13 with Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174.

If I log in fast, before "networks available" message shows up in login screen, wifi doesn't work. It also doesn't work after suspend. Restarting network manager helps.

What could be behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually only the panel indicator where the problem was. Wifi did work but the panel didn't show the connection correctly.

This fixed the indicator

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-network
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this behavior started with 16.04.  I never had to do this for years.  But at present you have to `edit the connection` from the network icon in the notification bar and enable `Automatic connection` and `All users`.

**The steps are:**

Click on `Network Icon` -> (Click) `Edit Connections` -> (Select) the `Wi-Fi Connection name` -> (Click) `Edit` -> (Click the tab) `General` -> Place checkmarks in:

```
    [ ] Automatically connect to this network when it's available
    [ ] All users my connect to this network.
```

(Click) `Save`.